# SSL сертификаты и PHP

Tags: php, сокет, ssl

господа. На стороне сервера крутится ssl сокет. С помощью этого кода хочу подключится и отправить данные.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'peer_name' => 'my.domain',
                'local_cert' => __DIR__.'/fullchain.pem',
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
        ));
        $notificator = stream_socket_client('ssl://127.0.0.1:3500', $errno, $errstr, 10, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
        //stream_context_set_option($notificator, $wrapper, $option, $notificator);
        fwrite($notificator, json_decode(array()));
        fclose($notificator);
```

Вылазит такая ошибка:

```
Unable to set private key file 'путь к fullchain.pem'
```

Сокет использует самоподписные сертификаты от letsencrypt. То что не может установить приватный ключ - вижу. Где взять сам приватный ключ?
Документация гласит:

**local_cert string**
Путь к локальному сертификату в файловой системе. Это должен быть файл, закодированный в PEM, который содержит ваш сертификат и закрытый ключ. Он дополнительно может содержать открытый ключ эмитента. Закрытый ключ также может содержаться в отдельном файле, заданным local_pk.

**local_pk string**
Путь к локальному файлу с приватным ключем в случае отдельных файлов сертификата (local_cert) и приватного ключа.

В **local_cert** я передаю локальный сертификат сокета.

Comment: Ну вы всё верно говорите, нужны 2 ключа. Откуда у вас ключ fullchain.pem? При создании сертификата letsencrypt выдаётся пара ключей.
https://habr.com/ru/post/270273/

Comment: @ ka3a сертификат выдан на определённый домен, я же обращаюсь к этому моменту из-под локалхоста. Я уже все комбинации перебрововал, пришёл к выводу, что лучше подключиться извне.